# What is the frequency of sound emitted due to two solids colliding?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acoustics

Let’s say that two objects collide and reproduce a sound with a given frequency or frequencies, what properties of these two solids determine the frequency or frequencies produced ?

Comment: Do you want the sound produced _inside_ the two objects, or do you want the sound that propagates _away from_ the two objects? Because if it's the latter, the properties of the medium surrounding the objects are also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more sources of sound than I will discuss here, but as a starting point...

Consider a tuning fork hitting the edge of a table.  The frequency of the sound produced by the tuning fork is a function of its **stiffness** and **mass**.  The tuning fork will vibrate at its fundamental frequency, but there will also be a small amount of sound at its [overtones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork).

Sound could also be created by the displacement of air caused by the **"shape"** of the collision.  For example, experiment with clapping your hands in different ways.  You can get different frequencies depending on how much you "cup" your palms.